# Windows software for monitoring remote server

Tags: networking, network-monitor

From a windows 7 desktop I need to monitor one service on one remote computer, HTTP.

What is the easiest tool that will allow me to do that?

I've looked at things like Nagios, Zabbix, Cacti, and others. They all seem a bit much, but as long the app is not too difficult to setup and maintain (not Nagios), I'm willing to look at it.

Anyone have any ideas which tool will get me up and running asap? Please, no scripts.

I don't want to have to use a database either.

Comment: Is the remote PC a server, and if so, 2008/12?

Answer (score 1):

10-Strike's monitoring programs are quite simple and can be set up in 5 minutes. You can use 10-Strike LANState or 10-Strike Network Monitor either.

http://www.10-strike.com/lanstate/

http://www.10-strike.com/network-monitor/

Both programs can monitor a service, generate email or SMS alerts, and can restart the service or the PC if necessary.

10-Strike Network Monitor operates as a service so it can be installed on a server. LANState does not have the service part but it has a visual network map so you can see the state of your devices or services in the real time on a graphic diagram (the program can scan your network topology as a bonus).

What you will need to do is to add a host (that remote computer), add a monitoring check to it (the service check), and configure the monitoring and alerting parameters.

Comment: Updated my first comment